# Make certain pages only available to certain users in django?

Tags: django

I'm building an ecommerce site with django.  I want to build a page that lists out all the orders created on a certain day, but i only want my staff to be able to have access to this page.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by staff, you mean the `is_staff` flag and not a custom group, then you can use this decorator before your view

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
... view ...
```